# Good looking sharethis / addthis / addtoany without javascript

Tags: html, share

Is there a good looking sharethis /addthis / addtoany alternative to share an url without javascript?

Like: `<a href="http://addthis.com?url=[...]">share</a>`

I already found this: http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=google.com&title=google, but it is very ugly and has too many options.

> Update: I am not looking for HTML, but for a service like http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=google.com&title=google, where I can give a url and the social sharing site handles links to facebook, twitter and google+.
>
> The only problem I have with addthis.com/bookmark.php is that it is ugly and has too many options. I only want links to facebook, twitter and google+.

Comment: Because of performance issues and possibilities to track users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? Pure css with some icing animation effect. NO JS.

[www.jsfiddle.net/Godinall/UH8sx/](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/UH8sx/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="show_social">Add to Social Networks
<div id="social_share">
    <p id="socialicons">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/SuperRodUK"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-eG9bPvyOXro/UPBYTmI8VEI/AAAAAAAAJqI/TFBZzBxJ59c/s1600/NBT+facebook+icon.png" /></a>  
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/SuperRodUK"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dB0P2JmL6QA/UPBYVfvhyII/AAAAAAAAJqU/HFD5UeTJck8/s1600/NBT+twitter+icon.png" /></a>  
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/ken@super-rod.co.uk"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XU8OI90JZQc/UPBYUKmev_I/AAAAAAAAJqM/FPgdcMimraQ/s1600/NBT+google+plus+icon.png" /></a>  
      <a href="http://www.feeds.feedburner.com/"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YPkJD-sewC8/UPBYWk9dzBI/AAAAAAAAJqg/D3FVlAJz4VE/s1600/NBT+rss+feed+icon.png" /></a> 
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/SuperRodUK"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YNToKMeHx9A/UPBYWVeeq5I/AAAAAAAAJqc/HEpC_PsZBsY/s1600/NBT+youtube+icon.png" /></a> 
    </p>
</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#show_social{width:400px;background:rgba(100,100,100,0.2);text-align:center;font-family:Helvetica;border:1px solid rgba(10,10,10,0.5)}
#social_share{display:none;}
#show_social:hover #social_share{display:block;}
#socialicons img {
     -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
 }
 #socialicons img:hover {
     -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
```

If you want to use a web service, they gonna track your usage anyway that's for sure. As for AddThis, they do have better layouts and simpler options, see this link:https://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers?frm=hp which is called smart layer that starts with only the 3 social services you prefer and the layout is HTML5 friendly.

Also the previous demo I gave you can also be modified to implement only the 3 social services you want and you can replace my handlers with your own. You can tweak the appearance as you wish.

Comment: I like it, but it is not what i'm looking for (see update in question).

Comment: see my edit, addthis has another option, and my previous demo could be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: I think what I want does not exists. And your jsfiddle solution is the best answer.

Comment: if you could describe your need in more details I'm more than happy to look deeper for you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for? It is very bad from UX point, nobody likes a new window being opened, when it could be just a pop-up.

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://helloworld.com/blog&text=Hello World" target="_blank">Tweet This button</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what i'm looking for. I am looking for one link that makes it possible to share via Facebook, Twitter and Google+. (and not all the other options in the link in my question).

Comment: I want to style the link myself via CSS.

Comment: Why do you need one link? A single href can only open one url without javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. I'm not looking for HTML, i'm looking for a webservice like http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=google.com&title=google

I only want it to be better looking and with less options (only facebook, twitter and google+)

I know I can also make three links, but I want only one link.

Comment: Sorry, but can't you help there. A webservice like this is bad for both performance and if you don't build it yourself it can track users.